Need help in python dictionary element updating and total dictionary replacement
Having a multi nested dictionary created from this json?
{ "config": [
         { "item_one": "value_one" },
         { "item_two": "value_two" },
         { "item_three": "value_three" }
    ]
}

After getting the dictionary from the file. Would updating value_two to new_value_two of item_two be done by the following:
file_dictionary["config"][1]["item_two"] = "\""+new_value_two+"\""

I'm working in python version 3.11
Also, could you replace a dictionary in the following manner?
file_dictionary = new_file_dictionary

Thank you for any answers to my questions.

You don't need the literal quotes in the value, just assign the string.
file_dictionary["config"][1]["item_two"] = "new_value_two"

file_dictionary = new_file_dictionary

reassigns the variable, it doesn't modify the dictionary. If there are other variables referring to the original dictionary, they won't be affected.
If you want to modify the dictionary in place, first remove all the old entries and than use .update() to copy the new dictionary's entries into it.
file_dictionary.clear()
file_dictionary.update(new_file_dictionary)


Will this replace all the dictionary data with the new dictionary data or will it nest the new dictionary with an existing empty dictionary?

It will replace it. Try it and see.
